# Отдельный поток для функции Python

Tags: python, многопоточность, функции

Всем доброго времени суток,пытаюсь создать функцию, которая вызывается автоматически каждые 24 часа. Делаю это с помощью библиотеки shedule `import shedule` `schedule.every().day.at("21:25").do(dailydeleter)`, но не получается сделать так чтобы это всё дело не мешало выполнению основного кода. На данный момент имею:

```
def dailydeleter():
 print('123')
def run_scheduled():
 schedule.every().day.at("23:59").do(dailydeleter)
 while True:
  schedule.run_pending()
  time.sleep(1)
my_thread = Thread(target=run_scheduled)
my_thread.start()
print("so we have started this parallel thread - as we see it allows os to go on with our script")
my_thread.join()
```

В этом случае основной код не выполняется, подскажите пожалуйста что не так, заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ситуацию, то `my_thread.join()` ожидает окончания потока, который вы создали, и поэтому дальше ничего не выполняется.

Comment: Хм, не знаете как можно исправить ситуацию?

Comment: Так а где ваш основной код всё же? Если после thread.join(), то уберите join совсем или переставьте после основного кода